# How to get non-duplicate index of an array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have an array which gets updated at times, so the size of the array is arbitrary.

I would like to get a non-duplicate index from the array (note: not the element at index, but just the index).

The program runs every 1000ms, and I'm trying to get a unique index.

This is what I have so far:

```js
randomIndex = data => {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
  if (rand !== Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)) {
    return rand;
  } else {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
  }
};
```

Yet still returns duplciate values

## Edit

Suppose we have `data = ['bob', 'charli', 'kate']`

I would like to get a random index e.i. 0 or 1 or 2.

Because I have `setInterval(() => {}, 1000)` currently i get the same index after 1000s, which is not what I want. So for every second, I need a different index.

## Update

Note that when I say no duplicate, what I really mean is that I do not want the same index to appear consecutively.

So say after 1s we have index 1, then the next 1s after, I want either 0 or 2.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'non-duplicate index'?

Comment: What are you trying to do in your code? if the if is false, the second `Math.random` can still return the same value as rand

Comment: I assume you want a function that returns an array index but that index should not be duplicated?. Always unique??

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Please check the update

Comment: @F.bernal Yes, just the index which is different every 1000s

Comment: That function has no sense to do that. You are no checking if the generated value was returned before.

Comment: @F.bernal For the sake of this question I've used setInterval as an example, but really, I need a unique index from the array when an event listener has been triggered.

Comment: @F.bernal Please check my update

Comment: @Does see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this function:

```js
let people = ['bob', 'charli', 'kate', 'bobby', 'jake', 'john', 'jerry', 'isaac'];

getRandIndex = (data, noRepeat) => {
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (data.length));
  while(noRepeat === rand) {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (data.length));
  }
  
  return rand;
  
};

let r = -1;

setInterval(() => {  
  r = getRandIndex(people, r);
  
  console.log(r);
  
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of a history of indexes to avoid duplicates. This example also uses recursion to keep trying to find a unique index. If there are none unique left, reset the history array. Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Looks like you don't actually need to keep track of 'history', rather just the last chosen index. This should get you where you need to be.

```js
let people = ['bob', 'charli', 'kate', 'bobby', 'jake', 'john', 'jerry', 'isaac'];
let lastIndex;

getRandIndex = (data) => {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (data.length));
  if (!lastIndex) {
    lastIndex = rand;
    return rand
  }
  if (rand != lastIndex) {
    lastIndex = rand;
    return rand;
  } else {
    return getRandIndex(data);
  }
};

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(getRandIndex(people))
}, 1000)
```

Comment: That function has a problem. Infinite when all the unique indexes where covered.

Comment: I think it has to be `return  getRandIndex(data);`

Comment: This is still returning duplicates. Tried it

Comment: The reason why this returns duplicate is when we clear the array, and the next random number generated, is still the same as previosuly removed number

Comment: Sebastian was right, needed to add that return statement. Check updated answer, should work.

Comment: Its not returning any duplicates. It will find a unique index until they have all been used up and then empty the array and start over.

Comment: No, my point is that you're using an array to make sure that all the values appear once. But that's, not the issue. The issue is, I don't want the same value to appear consecutively.

Comment: So for example: expected: 0,1,2,1,0, etc... But not: 0,0,1,2,2

Answer (score 0):

To do your task you need to use the `do...while` language construct, it will keep generating a new random number if the current random number is the same as the last one.

Here's a snippet to illustrate:

> In the snippet I'll use the `setInterval` method which doesn't allow the callback function(the first argument) to return a value, so you can assign the generated number to a variable and you can stop the interval using the reference variable(the variable that the `setInterval` method is assigned to) by using the `clearInterval` method. And also, I end the interval after 5 seconds.

```js
var data = ['bob', 'charli', 'kate'],
    l = data.length,
    lastIndex = -1,
    counter = 0;
intervalID = setInterval(getRandom, 1000);
function getRandom() {
  do {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);
  } while (r === lastIndex);
  lastIndex = r;
  console.log('data: ' + data[r] + ' | random_number: ' + r);
  if(++counter === 5) {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
}
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean way to do this

```
let previous = 0;
getRandIndex = (data) => {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
  if(rand == previous) return getRandIndex(data);
  previous = rand;
  return rand;
};
```